# Find the most and the least used value from a MySQL table

Tags: mysql, database

I have a problem in finding the most and the least used value in the table.
The thing is that I have the values on two different columns and after I merge them together, I can't find the correct way of ordering them by the number of entries.

Firstly I have a table for each station

```
drop table if exists stations;
create table stations (
    id_station int not null auto_increment,
    st_name varchar (100),
    primary key (id_station)
)auto_increment = 2000;

insert into stations values     (null, 'Kobenhavn H'),
                                (null, 'Orestad'),
                                (null, 'Tarnby'),
                                (null, 'CPH Lufthavn');

select * from stations;
```

The table with the tickets contains all the information about the stations in use.

```
     drop table if exists tickets;
     create table tickets (
        id_ticket int not null auto_increment,
        starting_point varchar (100),
        ending_point varchar (100),
        id_train int,
        departure_date date,
        primary key (id_ticket),
        foreign key (id_train) references trains (id_train)
    )auto_increment = 100;
```

As you can see, the most used value is `2000` which is used `4` times; and the least used value is `2001` which is only used `1` time.

```
insert into tickets values  ( null, 2000, 2003, 1, '2018.05.14'),
                            ( null, 2000, 2003, 1, '2018.05.14'),
                            ( null, 2003, 2000, 1, '2018.05.18'),
                            ( null, 2002, 2000, 3, '2018.06.2 '),
                            ( null, 2001, 2002, 3, '2018.06.4 ');

select * from tickets;
```

Here I must find the least and the most crowded station

I have tried to `union all` in order to get the two columns into one.

```
(select starting_point as 'All stations in use' from tickets)
    union all
(select ending_point from tickets);
```

The part from above works perfectly, but the problem is that I don't know how to link it with the following part.

```
SELECT 
    stations.id_station AS 'All stations in use',
    COUNT(*) AS 'Number of passengers'
FROM 
    (SELECT starting_point 
     FROM tickets
     UNION ALL
     SELECT ending_point from tickets) as Unix, stations
     GROUP BY stations.id_station
     ORDER BY COUNT(*);
```

What I wanted to obtain is:

```
2000    4
2003    3
2002    2
2001    1
```

Where `2000`, `2003`, `2002` and `2001` are `the stations in use` either from the first query or from the table `stations`

But what I get is:

```
2000    10
2001    10
2002    10
2003    10
```

I hoped that I could use something like `where stations.id_station = Unix` in the hope that I will solve the problem, but it won't work and I get the following error

> Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'Unix' in 'where clause'.

Can anyone help me please? I have been working on it for hours and I couldn't find any solution...

Kind regards,

Alin Chiver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a `union all`

```
select point, count(*) from (
select starting_point point
from tickets
union all 
select ending_point
from tickets) t
group by point
```

Comment: It is working perfectly, thank you very much sir! I don't really know how you did it and I would really appreciate a few coments on it, as I am a student who's new into MySQL. But anyway, thank you again!

Comment: @Alin This query produces a list of all stations and their count, not the most and least used stations. How does this answer your question?

Comment: @Bohemian Well, I have just added by myself an `order by count(*) asc` and it seems to work now :D